# Makefile Fatal Error When Installing Git through TarBall(No such file or directory)

Tags: git, makefile

I was attempting to install Git through it's tarball, and I came across a few missing file errors. How might I fix this?

```
/bin/sh: 1: curl-config: not found
GIT_VERSION = 1.7.10.1
/bin/sh: 1: curl-config: not found
    * new build flags or prefix
    CC daemon.o
In file included from cache.h:4:0,
                 from daemon.c:1:
git-compat-util.h:168:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:2132: recipe for target 'daemon.o' failed
make: *** [daemon.o] Error 1
nathan@tibbitts-family:~/src/git-git-9dfad1a$ make install
/bin/sh: 1: curl-config: not found
    CC daemon.o
In file included from cache.h:4:0,
                 from daemon.c:1:
git-compat-util.h:168:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:2132: recipe for target 'daemon.o' failed
make: *** [daemon.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To compile from sources you need a number of [external dependencies](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bf505158d0292eed441fff1bc9157da19645ee91/INSTALL#L80). In your case you need development files for `libcurl` and `openssl`. Something like `libcurl-dev`, `libcurl-openssl-dev`, `openssl-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

For my CentOS 7, I used these installation commands:

```
sudo yum -y install gcc  [Use this if cc is not already installed]
sudo yum install libcurl-devel
sudo yum install --assumeyes openssl-devel
sudo yum install expat-devel
```